# How to archive thousands of files into multiple 7-Zip archives without using the 7-Zip split function?

Tags: batch, 7-zip

I need to archive files into 7-zip archives that are each under a user defined size (in GB).  I can't use the split function in 7-Zip as that would prevent the user on the other end receiving my files, extracting them, and working on them until they had all the files in the split volume.  The files I am working with are organized into monthly folders inside yearly folders.

I need to maintain folder structure, so I want each monthly folder to contain 7-Zip archives for that folder only. I also want it to clean up the source files once the archives are created. The script should run on the 'Parent Folder' and archive all files below it, maintaining folder structure.

Comment: Only option I can see is to write a script that does that. It will be a fun challenge. Especially with your peculiar requirements. What languages are you comfortable with? Should be easy to get a rough version using PowerShell and `Get-ChildItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up answering my own question...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
::set max 7z archive -- 200MB = 209,715,200
set MaxBag=210000000
echo ******************************************************************************************
echo 'PruneNBag.cmd' uses the current path it is placed in as the cleanup point, called 'TreeTop'
echo All files in all subfolder(s) below the TreeTop will be condensed into 7z archives.
echo ******************************************************************************************
:Ask
::Confirm current working directory is the intended 'TreeTop'
echo Current Directory is:  "%CD%"  Use as 'TreeTop'?  (Y/N/exit)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no
If /I "%INPUT%"=="exit" goto exit
echo Incorrect Input & goto Ask
:yes
set treetop=%CD%
echo Pruning current directory, %treetop%
"%PROGRAMFILES%\7-Zip\7z.exe" h * "!Bag!" "%treetop%\%%a\%%b"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000>nul
    FOR /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad %treetop%') DO (
        set BagCounter=1
        FOR /f %%b in ('dir /b %treetop%\%%a') DO (
            set Bag=%treetop%\%%a\%%a-!BagCounter!.7z
            "%PROGRAMFILES%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx0 "!Bag!" "%treetop%\%%a\%%b" -sdel
            FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('!Bag!') DO (
                set BagSize=%%~zA
                echo bagsize is !BagSize!
                echo maxbag is !MaxBag!
                if !BagSize! GEQ !MaxBag! set /a BagCounter += 1
                echo BagCount is !BagCounter!
            )
        )
    )
echo Pruning operations complete...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000>nul
goto end
:no
echo Place PruneNBag.cmd in 'TreeTop' folder root and run again.
pause
echo closing...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000>nul
exit
:end
echo closing...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 2 -w 2000>nul
exit
```